# update element of array inside dataset based on condition in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset having format

```
scala> rxClaimsUpdated.take(1)
res0: Array[(String, Array[String])] = Array((186037020,Array(
    22960551, 
    hfeu0ysji96afjdicbmqbheop0zsbfuvs4ongjb6yqg=,
    095aa9d791b7b0b0f7f312435b8e30f1, 
    2016-10-15, 
    2015-02-13, 
    00186037020, 
    10, 
    30,  
    "",  
    20)))
```

for the inside array i want to update 9th element(last) if its value is 0.(in the given sample value is 20).

code i tried which is giving error is

```
val rxClaimsUpdatedtemp = rxClaimsUpdated.map(z => 
    if(z._2(9).toInt == 0) z._2.updated(9,1) 
    else z._2(9)
)
```

find my error below

```
<console>:55: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a
Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types 
(case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  
Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.

       val rxClaimsUpdatedtemp = rxClaimsUpdated.map(z => if(z._2(9).toInt == 0) z._2.updated(9,1) else z._2(9))
                                                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the `Array[String]` with `Integer` so it is throwing the error.

Here is what you can do

```
rxClaimsUpdatedtemp.map(z => {
  if (z._2(9).toInt == 0) { //check of zero 
    z._2.update(9, "1")
    z // update with above code and return the array
  }
  else z   //return default array
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: <console>:53: error: value z is not a member of Array[String]

Comment: I hope you missed something, I see everything fine with this code

Answer (score 0):

The error is rightly pointed out by Shankar Koirala above that you are trying to update element of Array[String] with an Int. another approach for the same solution:

```
val rxClaimsUpdatedtemp = rxClaimsUpdated.map { elem =>
    (
        elem._1, 
        elem._2.take(elem._2.length-1) ++ {if (elem._2.last == 0) Array("1") else Array()}}
    )
}
```

Here, the type of the rxClaimsUpdatedtemp will be same as rsClaimsUpdated as here we are preserving the first elements of the tuple while updating the second elements.

Logic for updating the second elements: take the n-1 elements from array of size n and append empty array Array() or Array("1") after checking the last element of the array.